# retrieving an autonumumber primary key field

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I've this function to retrieve employee details in my Employees table. I am using vb.net 2012 and MS Access for my database. My problem is how to retrieve employee details using their ID's with an autonumber and primary key attributes/datatype? here's my code:

```
Public Sub DisplayEmployeeDetail()

    Try
        sqlEmployeeInfo = "SELECT * FROM tblEmployees WHERE tblEmployees.ID = " + txtDTRidnum.Text + ";"
        Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlEmployeeInfo, con)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "tblEmployees")
        Dim temp = ds.Tables("tblEmployees").Rows.Count
        For i = 0 To temp - 1
            lblFname.Text = CStr(ds.Tables("tblEmployees").Rows(i).Item("FirstName"))
            lblLname.Text = CStr(ds.Tables("tblEmployees").Rows(i).Item("LastName"))
            lblMname.Text = CStr(ds.Tables("tblEmployees").Rows(i).Item("MiddleName"))
            lblAddress.Text = CStr(ds.Tables("tblEmployees").Rows(i).Item("Address"))
            lblPosition.Text = CStr(ds.Tables("tblEmployees").Rows(i).Item("Position"))
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error in load: " & ex.ToString, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

End Sub
```

it gives System.Data.OleDb.Exception: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'tblEmployees.ID='

Comment: Use parameters and this issue would not happen... Also your employeeid should be an integer type, not a string... and remove the semicolon.

Comment: Also... use & for string concatenation, not the mathmatical operator +...  and try wrapping your columns and tables in brackets `[ ]`...

Comment: wow! I tried using parameters errors were gone but it does not return any rows

Answer (score 0):

use single quotes like this:

```
sqlEmployeeInfo = "SELECT * FROM tblEmployees WHERE tblEmployees.ID = '" + txtDTRidnum.Text + "';"
```

Additional you can try this even you don't want to use:

```
Private Sub getData()
        Dim empDA As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        Dim empDS As DataSet = New DataSet
        Dim empTable As DataTable = New DataTable("EMPLOYEES")
        Dim adoConn As ADODB.Connection = New ADODB.Connection()
        Dim adoRS As ADODB.Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset()

        Try
            empTable.Columns.Add("FirstName", Type.GetType("System.String"))
            empTable.Columns.Add("LastName", Type.GetType("System.String"))
            empTable.Columns.Add("MiddleName", Type.GetType("System.String"))
            empTable.Columns.Add("Address", Type.GetType("System.String"))
            empTable.Columns.Add("Position", Type.GetType("System.String"))
            empDS.Tables.Add(empTable)

            'Use ADO objects from ADO library (msado15.dll) imported
            ' as .NET library ADODB.dll using TlbImp.exe

            'Specify your connection string here
            adoConn.Open("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;", "", "", -1)
            adoRS.Open("SELECT * FROM tblEmployees WHERE tblEmployees.ID = " + txtDTRidnum.Text + ";", adoConn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly, 1)
            empDA.Fill(empTable, adoRS)

            Dim temp = empTable.Rows.Count
            For i = 0 To temp - 1
                lblFname.Text = CStr(empTable.Rows(i).Item("FirstName"))
                lblLname.Text = CStr(empTable.Rows(i).Item("LastName"))
                lblMname.Text = CStr(empTable.Rows(i).Item("MiddleName"))
                lblAddress.Text = CStr(empTable.Rows(i).Item("Address"))
                lblPosition.Text = CStr(empTable.Rows(i).Item("Position"))
            Next

            adoRS.Close()
            adoConn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error in load: " & ex.ToString, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            adoRS.Close()
            adoConn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

This Example [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa325907(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: It gives "Datatype mismatch in criteria expression" if I use single qoutes

Comment: is datatype of your ID is integer? It is no bearing even you put single qoute

Comment: yes its Integer data type. i tried converting txtDTRidnum.text into integer but it give another error not in correct format

Comment: what is the value of your txtDTRidnum.text.. Did you try to change + to & like '" & txtDTRidnum.text & "'

Comment: The values inputted inside the txtDTRidnum are all numeric like 106392. I've tried both & and + the give me syntax error (missing operator) exception

Comment: what is the of sqlEmployeeInfo  after execution?

Comment: You never open your connection.

Comment: The dataadater will open the connection when the `Fill` is called... @reds

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because the text field txtDTRidnum.Text is empty.